# Azure-Bicep: How to add blob container to Storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

So, I have a StorageAccount.bicep

```
//StorageAccount.bicep
param storageAccountSku string = 'Standard_LRS'
param storageAccountName string
param storageAccountType string = 'StorageV2'

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-08-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  tags: tags
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountSku
  }
  kind: storageAccountType
}

output name string = storageAccount.name
```

In the main.bicep, it calls StorageAccount.bicep to create container.

```
module storage_account_1 'modules/storageAccount.bicep' = {
  name: 'storage_account1'
  scope: rg
  params: {
    storageAccountSku: 'Standard_LRS'
    storageAccountType: 'StorageV2'
    storageAccountName: 'storage_account1"
}
}
```

2nd storage account

```
var storageName = toLower('${envType}${rgNameUid}${toLower(app)}')
    module storage_account_2 'modules/storageAccount.bicep' = {
      name: 'storage_account2'
      scope: rg
      params: {
        storageAccountSku: 'Standard_LRS'
        storageAccountType: 'StorageV2'
        storageAccountName: storageName 
    }
    }
```

Then I have another helper.bicep that can set or override any settings.

```
//helper.bicep
resource my_storage 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01' existing = {
  name: storageName 
}
```

My question is how to add blob container to the 2nd storage account?

I tried to create blobContainer.bicep and then call it from main.bicep.

```
param storageAccountName string
param storageAccount object
@description('Name of the blob container to deploy.')
param blobContainerNames array
var cleanedContainerNames = [for x in blobContainerNames: toLower(x)]

resource blobContainers 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2022-05-01' =  [for containerName in cleanedContainerNames: {
  name: '${storageAccountName}/default/${containerName}'
  dependsOn: [
    storageAccount
  ]
  properties: {
    publicAccess: 'None'
  }
}]

output name string = blobContainers.name
```

But it errors in following line, can I declarer param as module to pass in?

```
dependsOn: [
    storageAccount
  ]
```

**Update:**

Can I do something like this?

```
//helper.bicep

resource my_storage 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01' existing = {
  name: storageName 
}

//Add the following lines
resource storagecontainer 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2022-05-01' = {
   name: '${storageName}/default/mycontainer'
   dependsOn: [
       my_storage 
     ]
   }
```

Comment: try instead of dependsOn use a parent property -> parent: storageAccount and put the dependsOn in main.bicep when referencing this module.  Might need to add an existing in blobContainer.bicep to get the parent based on the storageAccountName .

Comment: @ScottMildenberger Thanks, what should I declare storageAccount? I got "The property "parent" expected a value of type "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices" but the provided value is of type "object"." I also added existing, but seems not working.

Comment: add the block you have in helper.bicep into blobContainer.bicep and then use my_storage reference for the parent.  Also you probably only need containerName for the name after you get the parent reference sorted out.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger Sorry, I'm newbie to bicep. The parent is expected 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices but the storage I passed in is Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-03-01. Another question is can I add container in helper.bicep?

Comment: You could put all in helper.bicep.  I looked closer and you need two levels, the storage account and then blob service.  See this to create container called input: resource storageAccount_Resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-09-01' existing = {
  name: storageAccount_Name
}
resource blobService 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-09-01' existing = {
  parent: storageAccount_Resource
  name: 'default'
}
resource blobService_container 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2021-09-01' = {
  parent: blobService
  name: 'input'
  // etc
}

Comment: @ScottMildenberger Thanks, I add a few lines to helper.bicep insetad of blobContainer. Do you think this is going to work(I updated post).

Comment: in your blobContainer.bicep, you don't need a dependsOn. Also not sure what is the helper file is doing ? In bicep it is a module that will be deployed so you probably will run into some issues.

Comment: You need to have the 3 parts, storage account, blob service, and then the container.  See the code in my comment above or Thomas answer.  Thomas answer puts all the pieces in one module.  If you need the container in a separate module then reference the needed pieces with existing.  Best to put together a sample and test it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always add the containers creation inside the storage module:

```bicep
// StorageAccount.bicep
param storageAccountName string
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param tags object = {}
param storageAccountSku string = 'Standard_LRS'
param storageAccountType string = 'StorageV2'
param containerNames array = []

// Create storage
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-08-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  tags: tags
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountSku
  }
  kind: storageAccountType
}

resource blobService 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'default'
  parent: storageAccount
}

// Create containers if specified
resource containers 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2021-06-01' = [for containerName in containerNames: {
  parent: blobService
  name: !empty(containerNames) ? '${toLower(containerName)}' : 'placeholder'
  properties: {
    publicAccess: 'None'
    metadata: {}
  }
}]

output name string = storageAccount.name
```

Comment: // Create containers if specified. Does this mean it only create container if I pass in containerNames array = [], If I create an empty array, it doesn't create container?

Comment: I have multiple modules that calls the storageaccount.bicep but I only want specific storage account to create the container

Comment: Yes it's an optional param so by default empty

Comment: what is blobService for?